# Supposed Uniqueness Theorem Corollary

Tags: electrostatics

Following my instructor's notes the statement of the Uniqueness Theorem(s) are as follows

"If $\rho_{inside}$ and $\phi_{boundary}$ (OR $\frac{d \phi_{boundary}}{dn}$ ) are known then $\phi_{inside}$ is uniquely determined"

A few paragraphs later the notes state

"For the field inside S (a surface), knowing $\phi_{boundary}$ (OR $\frac{d \phi_{boundary}}{dn}$) everywhere on S is as good as knowing all the outside charges; it carries all the same information about their effects"

I don't see how this follows from the statement of the Uniqueness Theorem. If anything it **seems to me** that the instructor is saying the converse of the Uniqueness Theorem while flipping definitions of "inside" and "outside".

"If $\phi_{boundary}$ (OR $\frac{d \phi_{boundary}}{dn}$ ) are known on surface S then $\rho_{outside}$ is uniquely determined"

Can anyone help me

1. decipher what my instructor is trying to say
2. Offer help in the way of a formal proof or a convincing physical argument

\

Comment: Is S in the second instance empty by any chance?

Comment: @noah The notes do not indicate. For the sake of argument let's suppose it is because I'm curious to hear what you have to say.

Answer (score 0):

> "If $\phi_{\text{boundary}}$ (*or* $\frac{d \phi_{\text{boundary}}}{dn}$ ) is known on surface $S$, then $\rho_{\text{outside}}$ is uniquely determined"

This is not what the paragraph is trying to say.

> "For the field inside $S$ (a surface), knowing $\phi_{\text{boundary}}$ (*or* $\frac{d \phi_{\text{boundary}}}{dn}$) everywhere on $S$ is as good as knowing all the outside charges; it carries all the same information about their effects"

It is saying that no matter what $\rho_\text{outside}$ *exactly* looks like, the only thing that matters for the field inside $S$ is the field it produces on the surface $S$. So it is pretty much exactly saying what your first paragraph tells you, minus the charges inside $S$. But from superposition it follows that the total field inside is determined by the influence of the outside charges (for which we only need to know $\phi$ on $S$), and the charges inside $S$, yielding the statement in your first paragraph.